# Part and Span: is there a reason this *should* not work?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica

This is a question of design, not of existing functionality.

I would like to use:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[{1 ;; 3, 2 ;; 5}]]
```

I expect:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

But it is not valid:

```
During evaluation of In[1]:= Part::pspec: Part specification {1;;3,2;;5} is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
```

I am not asking *why* this does not work (simple: it's not supported).

Rather, is there a reason it *should not* work?  That is, is there a logical reason this is not supported?

---

By the way, I specifically did not ask about the nested list syntax like:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}]]
```

because I believe that is less "regular" and more volatile, while `Span` is more defined and controlled.

Comment: This is one functionality I have sorely missed. I've always ended up doing `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[#]] & /@ {1 ;; 3, 2 ;; 5}`, which would've been nicer had it been built-in.

Comment: Part doesn't even allow a single `Span` in a list. E.g. `Part[List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], {Span[3, 4]}]`. Strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the real question that you are asking is why this does not work:

```
In[15]:= {1,2,3,4,5}[[{{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5}}]]

During evaluation of In[15]:= Part::pspec: Part specification 
{{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5}} is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>

Out[15]= {1,2,3,4,5}[[{{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5}}]]
```

because `Span` seems to be a more high-level wrapper implemented on top of `Part` (this is a guess). This same question  [has been asked](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/192d515c3bc505fe/a599b820dfdc026b) very recently on MathGroup. There wasn't a satisfactory answer, and my feeling is that from the user's viewpoint, this is just an omission - I don't see a fundamental reason why this should not work. Moreover, this feature would make life a lot easier in some cases.

From the technical/implementation viewpoint, I can speculate that this will go at odds with the extended `Part` assignment functionality. Specifically, we know that `Part` can be used not just for element extraction but for efficient element assignments, where whole regular structures (rectangular sub-matrices) can be assigned simultaneously, like

```
In[18]:= 
a = Table[i+j,{i,2},{j,4}]

Out[18]= {{2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6}}

In[21]:= 
a[[All,{2,3}]] = {{7,8},{9,10}};
a

Out[22]= {{2,7,8,5},{3,9,10,6}}
```

Should `Part` allow nested lists specification for positions, it should immediately provide assignment functionality for the non-rectangular sub-structures, or it will become much less intuitive to use (since there will be corner cases, etc). And I suspect that the latter is not easy to implement, because extended `Part` assignment functionality is probably based directly on the array memory layout. This will also create problems with packed arrays (for the same reason - they can not be ragged, must be rectangular). Perhaps, should Mathematica have very efficient ragged array structure (like linked lists) built-in, and this could be solved.

So, to summarize: it looks like, from the implementation viewpoint, such new functionality will introduce several tough problems, which may explain why this has not been done yet (again, this is a guess). Note also, that for element extraction, one can use `Extract` with prepared list of positions, to extract arbitrary substructures, and that will be almost as efficient as with using `Part`.

Comment: Thanks, Leonid.  Also, I updated my question with why I asked about `Span`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see what you mean, but as soon as you allow to pass a list of `Span`-s, the regularity of individual `Span` becomes irrelevant - your resulting sub-structure is still generally irregular.

Comment: I see what _you_ mean, but I still think it is more controlled, because you cannot enter something like `a[[{{1, {2}}, 3, {{4}}}]]` with `Span`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you allow simple lists of `Span`-s, there is no reason to not allow nested lists of them (from the general design viewpoint). But then, here we go (not quite the same as your expression but similar): `a[[{{1;;1,{2;;2}},3;;3,{{4;;4}}]`.

Comment: Okay, I guess you could restrict either one just as easily to one level, but somehow `Span` just seems simpler to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you could restrict - but this will create corner cases and be not an elegant design, IMO, and besides, this will still not solve the implementation issues I mentioned. OTOH, if those are solved, the general form will probably also be allowed. I don't object that `Span` in many cases is a more direct idiom, just saying that there is a more general design problem here.